# How to replace a string in a file after a X number of time in Python?

Tags: python

**Premise Explaination:**

I have this Python script Main.py that gathers distance and temperature and sends them to a text file, Data.txt. Currently I have it so that it replaces the string of text each time

**EDIT:**

Currently it is only printing one string of text and the code repeatedly overwrites this one line, what I want is for the code to print 10 lines of that string of text before overwriting the oldest line, just like in the example below.

**Example:**

```
# Main.py

while True:
    f=open("data.txt","a+")
    a = str(scan())+"\n"
    f.write(a);
    log.log("Wrote to file")
    log.log(a)
    with open("data.txt","rt") as fin:
        with open("data.txt","wt")as fout:
            for line in fin:
                fout.write(line.replace("scan()", "scan()"))
    f.close()
```

**Actual Output:**

```
[26.07, 32.31, 93.73, False] #it constantly overwrites this line.
```

**Question:**

How do I make it so that it prints out at least 10 lines of text before replacing the string?

**Needed Output Example:**

```
    #print out 10 strings of text
    [23.07, 32.31, 93.73, False] 
    [27.03, 36.34, 93.73, False] 
    [26.07, 34.36, 93.73, False] 
    [28.02, 32.21, 93.73, False] 
    [24.03, 22.31, 93.73, False] 
    [22.07, 28.31, 93.73, False] 
    [29.04, 32.21, 93.73, False] 
    [26.07, 32.31, 93.73, False] 
    [26.07, 32.31, 93.73, False] 
    [26.07, 32.31, 93.73, False]

#new string of text comes in [26.07, 32.31, 93.73, True]
expected output:
   [27.03, 36.34, 93.73, False] 
   [26.07, 34.36, 93.73, False] 
   [28.02, 32.21, 93.73, False] 
   [24.03, 22.31, 93.73, False] 
   [22.07, 28.31, 93.73, False] 
   [29.04, 32.21, 93.73, False] 
   [26.07, 32.31, 93.73, False] 
   [26.07, 32.31, 93.73, False] 
   [26.07, 32.31, 93.73, False] 
   [26.07, 32.31, 93.73, True]  # replaces the string one, adding this new data into the list.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using `time.sleep()` so that you only write to the file every second or so.

```
import time
import numpy as np

def scan():
    # your scanner here. 
    return list(np.random.randint(1, 10, 4))

a_list = list()

while True:
    a = str(scan()) + "\n"
    a_list.insert(0, a)
    a_list = a_list[:10]

    with open("data.txt", "wt") as fout:
        fout.write(''.join(a_list))
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion it did append like it was suppose to but for some reason it was really slow even after removing the time.sleep

Comment: @yongjie maybe it's slow because of your scan function

Comment: The scan function is still printing out every 1 second hence I do not believe that is the problem, I think it might be the fact I am running on a Raspberry Pi for this and it might not have enough processing power?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while True:
    txt = open("data.txt", "r").read()
    txt = txt.split("\n")
    if len(txt) == 10:
        txt.pop(0)
        txt.append("what you want to write")
    else:
        txt.append("what you want to write")
    f = open("data.txt", "w")
    f.write("\n".join(txt))
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i have tried your solution  but unfortunately I could not get it to print the scan() string. i tried `txt.append(str=(scan())` but to no avail, do you have a solution to this?

Comment: you can stor the scan returning value in a variable and then append it a a string in txt

Comment: Ah thank you, i got it to run now but I believe this is not the function i was looking for, the code check for text length what I am looking for is to keep a constant line just like in my example. Regardless, thank you again for your time it still did help me in further understanding python.

Comment: You are welcome, if you edit your answer clarifying the problem i will be happy to help you